# Slice indices TypeError and Insert list method weird behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I have the following code:

```
a = [[0, 4]]
b = '1','2','3','4','5'
c = '*a3b*'

for f in b:
    if (f in c[a[0][0]:a[0][1]]):
        a[0].insert(0,f)
```

It returns:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

But the slice indices are already integers, aren't they? What's going on? I also did (and worked, don't know why):

```
a[0].insert(0,int(f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your loop has performed the `insert` once (for `'3'`), `a` has the value `[['3', 0, 4]]`. So the next time you try to slice, it's trying to slice `c['3':0]`, where before it was slicing `c[0:4]`.

Changing to `a[0].insert(0,int(f))` made it "work" by making `a`'s value `[[3, 0, 4]]`, so the slice became `c[3:0]`, which ends up slicing out nothing, but does it with valid integers. Your code logic looks very strange, but without knowing the goal, I can't provide any more suggestions beyond "You need to be more careful with your types" and "I'm not sure that `insert` is doing what you expect it to do".

Comment: Completely forgot that x)! Thanks!